# How do I show the "Up Next" queue on the iOS 11 Podcasts app?

Tags: podcasts, ios

In iOS 11, the Podcast app got a radical UI overhaul. I have figured out how to add podcasts to my queue of upcoming podcasts by selecting a podcast and choosing to "Play Next" or "Play Later".

How can I view this "Up Next" queue so that I can reorder it or delete things from it?

If it matters, I am interested in the app on an iPhone SE.

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone SE doesn't have 3D Touch so there is definitely a different step for you. If you go to the Now Playing screen, swipe up and you'll see the Up Next section. To add next podcasts, you'll need to tap on the menu button from the episodes detail view and then select Play Next. That should now show on your up next screen on Now Playing.

http://www.iphonehacks.com/2017/09/how-to-use-ios-11-podcasts-app-iphone-ipad.html

https://support.apple.com/en-ph/HT201859

Comment: I assume that the "Now Playing" screen is where it sows the cover art for the podcast currently playing, the time, and the controls to play/pause and advance or rewind 15 seconds. Swiping up shows the options to turn off wi-fi, bluetooth, etc. Scrolling up just shows the episode description. I do see the ellipsis button where I can play next, but again, can't find where to show what will be playing next.

Comment: Yes you are in the right place. It appears that you swiped up the control panel for iOS. Try swiping up a little higher, like on the cover art or just below it. Check out the images under "How to Build a Queue in Podcasts App" - http://www.iphonehacks.com/2017/09/how-to-use-ios-11-podcasts-app-iphone-ipad.html

Comment: Ah, there were two problems: you are supposed to scroll instead of doing a swipe from the edge. Also, the "Up Next" section only appears if you actually have something queued up. That's what threw me off: there was nothing queued up, so I couldn't see it.

Comment: Also, perhaps it would be good to embed a picture in your answer in case one of those sites goes down?

Comment: Ah, ok I thought you had something queued up next. And yes I should have added an image, but currently my job's server prevents image uploads to this site. Which is why I used that link.

Comment: I thought I had something queued up too, hence my confusion! Please add an image or two when you get a chance and I'll accept your answer unless better ones come along.

Comment: Sure, but I do have 3D touch, the process is different for those with 3D Touch support.

Comment: I’m not sure if they could have made that less obvious if they had tried. I had just assumed the app was rushed out the door to make the iOS 11 deadline and they forgot to include a way of viewing the up next queue.